# error en c: invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float *')

Tags: array, c

Este es la parte del código que me da el error:

```
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<h-1;j++)
    {
        C[3*i+j]=0;
        for(k=0;k<m-1;k++)
        {
            C[3*i+j]=C[3*i+j]+A[3*i+k]+B[3*k+j]; /*Aqui da el error*/    
        }
    }
}
```

la declaración fue así:

```
int i,j,k;

float A[2][3], B[3][3], C[6];
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero no pusiste la declaración de n,h,m.

Segundo sobre el error, es que cuando declaras a A y B, es que lo declaras como una matriz de 2*3 y de 3*3 respectivamente, pero cuando haces referencia a ellas lo haces es como si fuera un vector.